# purity scores of clusters in pyclustering library in python

Tags: python, cluster-analysis

I am trying to calculate purity scores of clusters using pyclustering library and I can't find a way to create a contingency matrix. Is there any way through which I can do it?

Comment: Hello and Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please note that it's always good to add more details to your question, plus what you've tried so far with code.